# amazon-cognito-identity-js - forgot password for Invalid User

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using amazon-cognito-identity-js node module for forgot password implementation.
Below is my service code.

```
 var userData = {
    Username: '<username>',
    Pool: '<userpool id>',
  }

var cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData)
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    cognitoUser.forgotPassword({
      onSuccess: function (data) {
        resolve({
          statusCode: 200, response: {
            ForgotPasswordResponse: {
              Status: 'Success',
              Destination: data.CodeDeliveryDetails.Destination
            },
          }
        })
      },
      onFailure: function (err) {
        resolve({
          statusCode: 400, response: {
            ForgotPasswordResponse: {
              Status: 'failure',
              Error: err.message
            },
          }
        })
      }
    });
  })
}
```

If I pass username which is not in pool, code still goes in onSuccess function and have no idea to which destination it is sending verification code.
Same thing happens if I pass username whose status in cognito userpool is  FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD.
Kindly suggest to handle this scenario.

Comment: Facing same issue... :(

Comment: Any inputs on this? I'm also having same issue

Answer (score 1):

Wen using amazon-cognito-identity-js to integrate Congito into a website for authentication, the forgotPassword method will not work properly if certain settings are flagged in the Cognito Pool.

Original Congtio interface navigation to settings
Cognito User Pool -> General Settings - > App Clients -> Show Details -> Security Configuration -> Prevent User Existence Errors

If you select "Enabled (Recommended)" then the forgotPassword API will never return a failure when submitting a user that does not exist in the User Pool.

If you switch it back to "Legacy" then the forgotPassword API works properly once again.

I have notified AWS of the issue, hopefully they will consider a fix.